# How can I run a certain conditional in powershell when a specific user logs in?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

For my desktop I have my own admin account and I am making a game account for my SO who wants to play games, username called Games. I have bitlocker on my games hard drive but if they log in I want a script to securely unlock the drive automatically without my needed to be there.

I have a script that prompts the bitlocker password already but how can I enhance this to say ?"If Games is the user, enter this password (preferably to have the password not hard coded in)  and unlock the drive.

```
$key = Read-Host 'Enter Bitlocker Password!' -AsSecureString

Unlock-Bitlocker -MountPoint "F:" -Password $key
```

Comment: Not necessarily powershell specific, but each user has a `shell:startup` folder that starts files when the user logs in. Type in `shell:startup` or `shell:common startup` into the `win-r` dialogue

Answer (score 3):

You can get the currently logged on user name with

```
PS> $env:USERNAME
Stephen
```

So to unlock this drive you could have a script that did the following

```
$allowedUsers = 'Stephen','Lindsey'

If ($allowedUsers.Contains($env:USERNAME)){
   #User is in allowed users group
   Unlock-Bitlocker...
}
```

Edit: I used the `.Contains()` method in the snippet above.  This method is case sensitive, so if you wanted a case-insensitive option, you could use the `-contains` operator instead like this.

```
$allowedUsers = 'Stephen','Lindsey'

If ($allowedUsers -contains $env:USERNAME){
   #User is in allowed users group
   Unlock-Bitlocker...
}
```

As for storing your password, I would normally suggest to store it as a `SecureString` but because this script will run against multiple  users, we would have issues retrieving a value encrypted against your profile, so I think you should take a look at the [PSSecret's Module](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secrets-management-development-release/), which should have work for your needs.

You could also always bake a password in using base64 or some other form of 'encraption'.

```
$sketchyPw = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("'myQuoteGamesDrivePasswordUnquote'"))

#back to plain

[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($sketchyPW))
```

So in your case you get the base64 password and then just bake that into your script which is probably safe enough for your use case here.

```
$key = convertto-securestring ([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('JwBIAGEAbABvAEkAcwBUAGgAZQBCAGUAcwB0ACcA'))) -AsPlainText -Force
$allowedUsers = 'Stephen','Lindsey'

If ($allowedUsers.Contains($env:USERNAME)){
   #User is in allowed users group
   Unlock-Bitlocker -MountPoint "F:" -Password $key
}
```

**Additional security option**
For reasonable security you could also store this base64 value in a regkey which you only allow read permission to for your account and your wife's.  Since others couldn't read it, they couldn't get the value without resorting to some pretty unlikely measures.

Comment: Don't you mean `($allowedUsers -contains 
 $env:USERNAME)` instead of the string `.Contains()` method?

Comment: Either way works, the if statement is only looking for a `boolean` value, and both will work just fine.

Comment: However.. `.Contains()` is case-sensitive while `-contains` is not. Logon names should always be treated case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but I get a few errors, even on my admin account.  Get-CimInstance : Access denied  and Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal : F: does not have an associated BitLocker volume.

Comment: When you log on as your wife's account, does she see an F:\ drive?  Perhaps the F:\ drive is automatically unlocked when you log in on your main profile?  These are all in-depth Bitlocker questions we'd have to research first.  Sounds like a good candidate for a second question 

Comment: Yes there is an F drive. I attempted to run the script on my account too and received the same error. odd..

Comment: I think this answer here functionally answers your initial question of how to conditionally run a command.  The next step would be to open a new BitLocker Specific question to see why this command might not be working.